# Org-mode: dots exported as ellipsis

Tags: org-mode, emacs24

When I export to ascii in org-mode 8.2.5h then this:

```
...
```

Is exported as this:

```
…
```

How do I prevent that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `org-export-with-special-strings` controls the translation of horizontal ellipsis and dashes. Turn off that variable (e.g. through `customize-variable`) to avoid translations.

To apply this setting only to a file or subtree, use the [`-` export option](http://orgmode.org/manual/Export-settings.html):

```
#+OPTIONS: -:nil
```

The affected translations are (as of orgmode 8.2.6):

```
 Org     HTML     LaTeX    UTF-8 
-----+----------+--------+-------
 \-    &shy;      \-             
 --    &ndash;    --         –   
 ---   &mdash;    ---        —   
 ...   &hellip;   \ldots     …
```